# Invalid SockJS path /topic/mytopic - required to have 3 path segments

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I've got a spring boot app in which I'm adding the websocket feature so that websocket client can make subscription request to subscribe messages off the websocket topic.

In my controller's method, I've added an annotation @SubscribeMapping("/topic/mytopic").

My WebSocketConfig looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguratioSupport{
   @Override
   public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry){
     registry.addEndpoint("/my-app")
             .setAllowedOrigin("*")
             .withSockJS();
   }

   @Override
   public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry){
     registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/");
     registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/");
 }
}
```

When I go to the browser and type:

```
http://localhost:<MY_PORT>/my-app
```

Then I get a response "Welcome to SockJS!". This indicates that Websocket server is indeed up and running.

But to my surprise, when I'm using my Postman's Websocket feature and trying to do a websocket subscription using the url:

```
ws://localhost:<MY_PORT>/my-app/topic/mytopic
```

This error is logged in the console: **Invalid SockJS path /topic/mytopic - required to have 3 path segments**

and the connection gets disconnected automatically.

Am I doing something wrong here? Please advise.